# Theanoのarangeについて

Tags: python, 機械学習

Deep Learning Tutorialsのロジスティック回帰を読んでいます。
http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html

ロジスティック回帰での尤度関数を計算する部分。

```
-T.mean(T.log(self.p_y_given_x)[T.arange(y.shape[0]), y])
```

ここの T.arange についてなのですが
Theano の arange は Numpy と同じように0〜nのベクトルを作成するのでしょうか？

```
print T.arange(10)
```

として、配列が作成されるか確認しましたが ARange.0 と出力され、どのように動作しているのかわかりません。

質問したい点は以下です。
- theano.tensor.arangeの動作について
- printした際の出力の意味

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

基本的な機能は numpy の arange と同じで、始点・終点・増分を指定して array を生成します。 
python 組み込み関数である range の numpy 版、theano 版とでも言いましょうか。

[numpy.arange document](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) を見てもらえれば分かると思いますが、

```py
>>> np.arange(3) # 長さ 3 の int 型の array を生成
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> np.arange(3.0) # 長さ 3 の double 型の array を生成
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
>>> np.arange(3,7) # [3, 7) の int 型の array を生成
array([3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> np.arange(3,7,2) # [3, 7) の 2 増分の int 型の array を生成
array([3, 5])
```

という風に使用します。
ただし theano の場合は theano の表現にエンコードされ、普通に `print` すると `ARange.0` と出力されます。
内部の値を参照したい時は

```python
>>> T.arange(5).eval()
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int8)
```

と最後に `eval()` を付けます。